# Yen's Algorithm implementation not choosing shortest paths

Tags: python, search, dijkstra, shortest-path

I am using Yen's Algorithm ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yen%27s_algorithm)) to find k shortest paths in a graph. In the example below, my graph is a dictionary where each node is a key, with its value being the neighbors. `Map()` from `dotmap` simply allows for dictionaries to be converted into an object where keys can be accessed with dot notation. I want to find the four shortest paths in descending order from A to F where every edge has equal weight. The first two are ties (A > B > D > F) and (A > E > D > F), and the next two are (A > B > C > G > F) and finally (A > B > D > C > G > F). It is possible that my implementation of Dijkstra's (called AStar despite having no heuristic) is flawed because it is returning an empty list when no path is found. How can I have my code only pick the valid paths? Currently it returns `[['A', 'B', 'D', 'F'], ['A', 'E', 'D', 'F'], [], []]` -- it should return `[['A', 'B', 'D', 'F'], ['A', 'E', 'D', 'F'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'G', 'F'], ['A', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'G', 'F']]` which are the shortest paths.

```
import copy
import heapq
from dotmap import Map
from itertools import count

graph = {
    'A': ['B', 'E'],
    'B': ['C', 'D'],
    'C': ['G'],
    'D': ['C', 'F'],
    'E': ['D'],
    'F': [],
    'G': ['F']
}

class PriorityQueue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.elements = []
        self._counter = count()

    def empty(self):
        return len(self.elements) == 0

    def put(self, item, priority):
        heapq.heappush(self.elements, (priority, item,))

    def get(self):
        return heapq.heappop(self.elements)[1]


class AStar:
    def __init__(self, graph, start, goals=[]):
        self.graph = graph
        self.start = start
        self.frontier = PriorityQueue()
        self.frontier.put(start, 0)
        self.previous = {}
        self.previous[start] = None
        self.costs = {}
        self.costs[start] = 0
        self.final_path = None
        self.goals = goals
        self.goal = None

    def search(self):
        graph = self.graph
        frontier = self.frontier
        goals = self.goals
        costs = self.costs
        while not frontier.empty():
            state = frontier.get()
            if state in goals:
                cost = self.costs[state]
                self.goal = state
                self.final_path = self.trace_path()
                return Map({'path': self.final_path, 'cost': cost})

            for next_state in graph[state]:
                new_cost = costs[state] + 1
                if next_state not in costs or new_cost < costs[next_state]:
                    costs[next_state] = new_cost
                    priority = new_cost
                    frontier.put(next_state, priority)
                    self.previous[next_state] = state
        # No path found
        return Map({'path': [], 'cost': 0})

    def trace_path(self):
        current = self.goal
        path = []
        while current != self.start:
            path.append(current)
            current = self.previous[current]
        path.append(self.start)
        path.reverse()
        return path

def YenKSP(graph, source, sink, k_paths):   
    graph_clone = copy.deepcopy(graph)
    A = [AStar(graph, source, sink).search().path]
    B = []

    for k in range(1, k_paths):
        for i in range(len(A[-1]) - 1):
            spur_node = A[-1][i]
            root_path = A[-1][:i+1]
            for path in A:
                if len(path) > i and root_path == path[:i+1]:
                    graph_clone[path[i]].remove(path[i+1])

            result = AStar(graph_clone, spur_node, sink).search()
            spur_path = result.path
            total_path = root_path[:-1] + spur_path
            spur_cost = AStar(graph_clone, source, spur_node).search().cost
            B.append(Map({'path': total_path, 'cost': result.cost + spur_cost}))
            graph_clone = copy.deepcopy(graph)
        if len(B) == 0:
            break
        B.sort(key=lambda p: (p.cost, len(p.path)))
        A.append(B[0].path)
        B.pop()
    return A

paths = YenKSP(graph, 'A', 'F', 4)
print(paths)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import copy
import heapq
#from dotmap import Map
from itertools import count

class Map(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, k):
        return self[k]
    def __setattr__(self, k, v):
        self[k] = v

graph = {
    'A': ['B', 'E'],
    'B': ['C', 'D'],
    'C': ['G'],
    'D': ['C', 'F'],
    'E': ['D'],
    'F': [],
    'G': ['F']
}

class PriorityQueue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.elements = []
        self._counter = count()

    def empty(self):
        return len(self.elements) == 0

    def put(self, item, priority):
        heapq.heappush(self.elements, (priority, item,))

    def get(self):
        return heapq.heappop(self.elements)[1]


class AStar:
    def __init__(self, graph, start, goals=[]):
        self.graph = graph
        self.start = start
        self.frontier = PriorityQueue()
        self.frontier.put(start, 0)
        self.previous = {}
        self.previous[start] = None
        self.costs = {}
        self.costs[start] = 0
        self.final_path = None
        self.goals = goals
        self.goal = None

    def search(self):
        graph = self.graph
        frontier = self.frontier
        goals = self.goals
        costs = self.costs
        while not frontier.empty():
            state = frontier.get()
            if state in goals:
                cost = self.costs[state]
                self.goal = state
                self.final_path = self.trace_path()
                return Map({'path': self.final_path, 'cost': cost})

            for next_state in graph[state]:
                new_cost = costs[state] + 1
                if next_state not in costs or new_cost < costs[next_state]:
                    costs[next_state] = new_cost
                    priority = new_cost
                    frontier.put(next_state, priority)
                    self.previous[next_state] = state
        # No path found
        return Map({'path': [], 'cost': float('inf')})

    def trace_path(self):
        current = self.goal
        path = []
        while current != self.start:
            path.append(current)
            current = self.previous[current]
        path.append(self.start)
        path.reverse()
        return path

def YenKSP(graph, source, sink, k_paths):
    A = [AStar(graph, source, sink).search().path]
    B = []

    for _ in range(1, k_paths):
        for i in range(len(A[-1]) - 1):
            graph_clone = copy.deepcopy(graph)

            spur_node = A[-1][i]
            root_path = A[-1][:i+1]
            for path in A:
                if len(path) > i and root_path == path[:i+1]:
                    if path[i+1] in graph_clone[path[i]]:
                        graph_clone[path[i]].remove(path[i+1])

            result = AStar(graph_clone, spur_node, sink).search()
            spur_path = result.path
            total_path = root_path[:-1] + spur_path
            spur_cost = AStar(graph_clone, source, spur_node).search().cost
            B.append(Map({'path': total_path, 'cost': result.cost + spur_cost}))

        if len(B) == 0:
            break

        B.sort(key=lambda p: (p.cost, len(p.path)))
        best_b = B.pop(0)
        if best_b.cost != float('inf'):
            A.append(best_b.path)
    return A

paths = YenKSP(graph, 'A', 'F', 4)
print(paths)
```

Produces:

```
[['A', 'B', 'D', 'F'], ['A', 'E', 'D', 'F'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'G', 'F'], ['A', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'G', 'F']]
```

The main issue was that when there was no path found, your default returned a path with 0 cost.  So when sorted by path cost, these paths were appearing as the best choice in `B` and being added to `A`.  I changed the default path cost to `float('inf')`.  Doing so revealed an error that could occur when you tried to remove the same edge twice from `graph_clone` (inside `for path in A: ...`), so I added an `if` check to conditionally remove the edge.  The two last things [the diff](https://www.diffchecker.com/JenTEakP) indicate that I did were (a) imitate your `dotmap.Map` class (you can remove this and uncomment the import), and (b) only add a path to the resultset `A` if the cost is finite.